# Convergence in Distribution

Tags: arrows

I'm reading a textbook on different forms of convergence, and I've seen several examples in the text where they have an arrow with a letter above it to indicate different types of convergence.  Does anyone know how to make that symbol?  I tried what I thought was the most obvious guess ("\to^P") but that didn't work...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use `\xleftarrow[]{}` and `\xrightarrow[]{}` from the `amsmath` package (you have to include it in your preamble using `\usepackage{amsmath}`).

For example this code `A\xleftarrow[f(x)]{n+\mu-1}B \xrightarrow[T]{n\pm i-1}C` generates

[image]